# Can someone playing Clash of Clans on Android change their email address?

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I have a member of my clan on Android, and he has to change his email.

Is there a way he can do this without resetting all his progress? He has been a loyal and valuable member and I would hate for him to lose his progress and have to start over.

Answer (score 1):

According to Supercell staff in [this forum thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906092438/http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/406853#2), your account is attached to your Game Center or Google Account. You can't change the savegame-attached email address by yourself. You need to contact Supercell Support for this.

[image: screenshot]

**How to contact Supercell Support:**

- Use the "Help and Support" button in the game. You can find the button in the settings.
- [Contact us - Supercell](https://support.supercell.com/clash-of-clans/en/articles/contact-form.html)
- Email: clashofclans.feedback@supercell.net

Answer (score 0):

I think he followed this method. I used this one few days ago and it worked fine:

Contact the support, tell them that you are using your company's email for playing game. But you are going to leave it because it is too far from your home. You are going to switching to a new company and your email will be deleted.

Comment: Try rereading the question, his friend did not follow any method, he is asking for one.